# Open putty window - is x11 forwarding enabled?

Tags: putty, x11-forwarding

If I have a putty window already open, is there a way to tell if x11 forwarding is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the contents of `$DISPLAY`; It should contain something like `:10`.

```
echo "$DISPLAY"
```